Transmit filename to main file while using !# tex root
I have, in a directory named tds, several files, say td1.tex, td2.tex etc. with no preamble but with the directive :
% !TEX root = ../main.tex

In this file main.tex :
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{import}
\begin{document}
\import{tds}{td1.tex}
\end{document}

This works fine but is it possible to replace td1.tex by the name of the file from which I'm launching the typesetting, for example I would like to open td2.tex in my editor and typeset it without having to open the main.tex file.
Edit : I use Texworks but I may change later to another editor.

% !TEX root = ../main.tex is just a comment not used by tex at all, so if it is being used it is being read by your editor to decide a commandline, so whether that commandline can be adjusted to record the file is a feature (or not) of your editor but you have not said which you are using. (several editors have variants of % !TeX comment directives.

but if your main file only includes one file, why do this at all it would be much simpler to put the \documentclass in each of your files and just process them as normal documents,

The idea was to get rid of the preambles in those documents but yes the simpler solution seems to be keeping a short preamble with the use of a document class. Thank you David for the response.

you can share preamble code with \input{sharedpreamble.tex} in the documents, using \import complicates all processing, even without the extra requirement to set the filename dynamically

If the issue is to have instant previews of subdocuments and use the main file only to see the whole project, take a look at docmute manual. A small example here.
